# How to detect invalid HTML in AngularJs (unmatched tags)

Tags: html, angularjs, validation

For plain old HTML, I use the [W3C validation service](https://validator.w3.org), but it has objections to Angualr directives.

I am having problens with `WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once`, and some possible solutions that I read suggest that it is caused by malformed HTML, specifically unclosed tags.

How can I detect such problems?

Obviously, I have checked that I am not directly including Angular twice

Comment: Well, first thing I'd do is check the lines where you're loading Angular and see if they can somehow run more than once.

Comment: Templates might also be a not-so-obvious place where it could be mistakenly loaded. Some frameworks may also bundle it so if you're using any minified/bundled scripts that may be a place to look.

Comment: Good points, but : I don't have any templates of my own creation, but will validate all those in the project. Hopefully minified scripts don't include HTML. In both cases, I am relying on thousands of other users to find any problems in common code which I use,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say proper indentation and a good IDE are the best tools you have on this front - personally I use PHPStorm (WebStorm would also do the same) for my Angular development which will highlight warnings for the angular attributes by default but highlight errors like unclosed tags/quotes etc. in red

Indentation prevents things like open tags, the IDE helps out with open quotation marks on attributes which are probably the 2 issues most likely to cause issues.

Comment: Good points (+1). As it happens, I use WebStorm. I also align indentation of my HTML tags.  I have several dozen HTML files, which I `ng-include` and am looking for an approach that does not require opening every one manually and looking for error marks

Comment: Using the inspect code function will allow you to check multiple files at once :). Right click a directory > inspect code

Comment: In WebStorm 2016, in the Project view on the left, I can see the files in the top level directory, but not the sub-directories :-(

Comment: Try right click > synchronize on the root directory (or one of the sub-directories) of the project - it should refresh the project view for whichever you click

Comment: I can only do that in the breadcrumb trail at the top of the IDE, but it doesn't show me the sub-directories in the project panel at the left, just the  files in the root directory

Comment: Take it that synchronizing the project root didn't make them appear? Only other thought I have is that maybe you're on something like the changed files project view or similar  (can change this from the top left of the project window)

Answer (score 1):

#### Angular doesn’t “see” your raw HTML

The real trick here is that JavaScript (and, in turn Angular) does not work directly with your HTML. It works with the page’s DOM, which is created from your HTML.

When a browser [creates a DOM from HTML](https://css-tricks.com/dom/), one of the major things is does is to "auto correct" any errors in the HTML. So, Angular won’t even see the errors in your HTML — it will just see the resulting “auto-corrected” DOM. (Of course, the more errors in your HTML, the more likely something would be auto-corrected in a way that causes you a problem.)

In theory, you could compare a page’s HTML source with the resultant DOM to find differences which might be errors. In practice, that would be highly problematic, and prone to reporting a high volume of false positives.

#### What then, can we validate HTML from web sites?

If you would like to validate your HTML markup from a web page, the best way would be to install your instance of a well-suppored HTML validator (like [W3C’s validator](https://validator.w3.org/docs/install.html)) and hook into that.

You can capture a page’s DOM with a little jQuery (which you most likely have if you are using AngularJS):

```
var domString = $("html").prop("outerHTML");
```

Then, just post that string as input to your favorite validator.

I think you would need to compare the validation of this DOM string to validation of the HTML, as an error in the raw HTML is more likely to be where your problem is.

Comment: hi, Tim (+1). As stated above, I _do_ use the W3C validator for plain vanilla HTML. I guess the trick would be to somehow capture the page as Angular sees it & feed taht to the W3C validator. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Angular HTML in my experience is rarely valid HTML5 you can make more of it valid if you prefix attribute directives with `data-`. I don't think that using element directives would ever validate. You could probably use filtering after validating to refine the output to better suit your needs - there's a button `Message Filtering` after validating. `Attribute ___ not allowed on element ___ at this point.` is at least one you'll very likely want to uncheck as a start